# Approaches to (non-linear) meta-regression to estimate the conditional population distribution of $y$ based on aggregate data

Tags: nonlinear-regression, splines, pooling, aggregation, meta-regression

I want to estimate the distribution of a variable in certain subgroups of the population based on pooling of aggregate data reported in various observational studies. For simplicity, assume there is a variable $y$ and an explanatory variable $x$, e.g. age, then for each observational study I have only aggregate data: $\bar{y}$, $\sigma_y$, $\bar{x}$, $\sigma_x$ and $N$, where $N$ is the number of individuals included to compute the sample statistics. Are there general approaches to this problem that can be extended to nonlinear models? (For example spline regression)

More specifically, I am interested in characterizing the likely range of values $y$ for a given value $X=x$, i.e. I want to infer the distribution $Y|X$.  I know that in reality $\operatorname{Var}(Y|X=x)$ is not constant, so I'd like to estimate $\sigma_{Y|X=x}$, and I expect that both $\operatorname{E}(Y|X=x)$ and $\operatorname{Var}(Y|X=x)$ are nonlinear with respect to $x$. Thus, I would be interested in some spline regression approaches, but overall I'm interested to know if there are existing frameworks (in R) that can be easily used to implement such a model.

I would expect that dealing with known/observed variabilities of $y$ and $x$ is a common problem in meta-regression of aggregate data, but from what I have seen it seems that most approaches are weighted with respect to the variability of the outcome variable and do not explicitly account for the observed variation of $x$ in each study. I have found an [approach to linear regression](https://rdrr.io/cran/IsoplotR/man/york.html) that is formulated to do exactly what I think makes sense, but only provides a single estimate of the variance over the range of $x$ and further assumes a linear relationship. Otherwise, I haven't found an example or documentation that seems to be designed to handle or use the known/observed variability of covariates. Further, most meta-analysis examples are focused on effects or effect sizes, whereas I'm interested in characterizing the population distribution, so I'm a bit unsure how to cast my objective into such frameworks.